# Qt when calling connect gives me an error

Tags: c++, debugging, qt

I'm having problem with connect. My problem is:
I have a class called eventos (events) that will manage all the objects events (buttons, lists etc...) but when I call an event, it gives me  an memory reading error.
Here is my code:

My main class:

```
#include "ratagbc.h"
#include "eventos.h"

RataGBC::RataGBC(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    eventos e;
    connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(e.on_runBtn_clicked()));
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

RataGBC::~RataGBC()
{

}
```

eventos.h:

```
#include QDialog.h
#include "ui_ratagbc.h"

class eventos : public QDialog, public Ui::RataGBCClass { 
    Q_OBJECT    
public:     
        eventos(void);
    ~eventos(void);

    public slots:       void on_runBtn_clicked(); };
```

eventos.cpp:

```
#include "eventos.h"
#include <QMessageBox>


eventos::eventos(void)
{
}


eventos::~eventos(void)
{
}

void eventos::on_runBtn_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox qb;
    qb.setText("Rata");
    qb.exec();
}
```

The error is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x776a15de in RataGBC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000964.

Debugging I realized (or guessed?) that the error seems to be in the SINGAL call.

Comment: You should really format your code properly. It helps people who would like to answer understand your problem instead of having to work just to read it. If you don't know how, take a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

The object  `eventos e`  has scope and lifetime limited by a constructor body. You should make it as a member of `RataGBC`; or inherit it from `QObject` (I don't see eventos.h, but I believe you have already inherited it as far as you use signal-slot mechanism for it) and create it dymamically as a child of `RataGBC`, like this

```
eventos * e = new eventos();
e->setParent(this);
```

or don't make it child, but just delete it in the destructor of the `RataGBC`

Comment: I tried that, but it keeps giving me the very same error. And btw, I put the eventos.h in the 1st post !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari what is `ui` ? Usually it is pointer and methods of it should be referenced with `->`.

Comment: it is auto created by Qt. It is a `Ui::RataGBCClass`. Thanks !

Comment: you mean qt creator? if it so, I've got like that `ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); /...`

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer please if it helps by pressing green "V"

Comment: and possibly try to put the `connect` down after setupUi, I'm not sure

Comment: and put pointer e in connect , not `this` : `connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),e,SLOT(e.on_runBtn_clicked()));`

Comment: Now, if I try doing connect (...,...,this,SLOT(close()); it works, it closes the program. But if I do connect (...,...,this,SLOT(e.on_runBtn_clicked()); it doesnt call the function. Do u have any idea why ? Thanks for the help so far !

Comment: `connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),e,SLOT(on_runBtn_clicked()));` (not e.on_runBtn_clicked()) sorry), and `e` should be pointer to object, not object.

Comment: Any ideas ? It seems the signal can't get recognized... Is there any config that needs to be done in Visual Studio 2010 to make it works ?

Answer (score 1):

your connect method is..

```
connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(e.on_runBtn_clicked()));
```

it means that whenever button clicked signal is emitted then for that signal qt will search for the slot in RataGBC class which is not having any such slot. for this to avoid u should replace the current receiver object i.e this by eventos object, as shown below..

```
connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),e,SLOT(e.on_runBtn_clicked()));
```

this will work for you..

Comment: almost... since `e` is an object, you instead need to pass `&e` to the connect function.  Also, the SLOT should then be `SLOT(on_runBtnClicked())` without the `e`

Comment: also, this (probably) only matters if the `eventos e` is moved out of the scope of the ctor (as pointed out in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try following code , your eventos e , object has scope limited to constructor and second you are using this as target object for slot, but you want e to be target. Also you should make e a class member variable and delete that in destructor.

```
eventos *e = new eventos();
connect(ui.runBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),e,SLOT(on_runBtn_clicked()));
ui.setupUi(this);
```